# Pythonic way of applying regex to all columns of dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe containing keywords and value in all columns. See the example below.

[image: Input DataFrame]

I want to apply regex to all the columns. So I use for loop and apply the regex:

```
for i in range (1,maxExtended_Keywords):
    temp = 'extdkey_' + str(i)
    Extended_Keywords[temp] = Extended_Keywords[temp].str.extract(":(.*)",expand=True)
```

And I get the desired final result. No issues there.

[image: Desired output]

However, just curios is there a pythonic way to apply regex to entire dataframe instead of using for loop and applying to column wise.

Thanks,

Comment: piRSqured's answer is excellent. In general, I don't think there's a problem with looping over Dataframe *columns*. You might want to replace the loop to `for c in Extended_Keywords.columns`, though.

Comment: More to @AmiTavory's point, often, dataframes don't have terribly many columns and I've seen cases where applying over 10 columns is faster than reshaping for the purpose of some overall vectorized solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` with `regex=True`

```
df.replace('^.*:\s*(.*)', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Notice that my pattern uses parentheses to capture the part after the `':'` and uses a raw string `r'\1'` to reference that capture group.

---

### MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan, 'thing1: hello'],
    ['thing2: world', np.nan]
], columns=['extdkey1', 'extdkey2'])

df

        extdkey1       extdkey2
0            NaN  thing1: hello
1  thing2: world            NaN
```

---

```
df.replace('^.*:\s*(.*)', r'\1', regex=True)

  extdkey1 extdkey2
0      NaN    hello
1    world      NaN
```

Comment: Very nice. It is somewhat odd that this doesn't require the `.str` construct, no?

Comment: the `str` accessor is for `Series` this applies to to the entire DataFrame.

Comment: You're right, but, hypothetically, in order to be consistent, there could be also a `DataFrame.str` accessor, I guess. But maybe I'm just not getting the logic, and it's nits anyway.

Comment: That would be nice!  What's even stranger is that Series has a `replace` method as well as `str.replace` that behave slightly different.

Comment: I’d appreciate feedback from the down voter if they are willing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use applymap, it will apply some function for each element in dataframe, for this problem you can do this:

```
func = lambda x: re.findall('^.*:\s*(.*)', x)[0] if re.findall('^.*:\s*(.*)', str(x)) else x
df.applymap(func)
```

**Caution**: Avoid to use applymap for huge dataframes due to efficiency issue.