# Replacing $ in column values while creating dummies in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have the below data where the column values contain $. This makes the dummies created to be of dtype unsigned integer. I am trying to replace the '$' with '' resolve the dtype issue.

**INPUT**

```
grp_m1      grp_m2      grp_m3      grp_m4
$50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75
$50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75     $50-$75
$150-$175   $150-$175   $150-$175   $150-$175
$100-$125   $100-$125   $100-$125   $100-$125
$150-$175   $125-$150   $125-$150   $125-$150
```

**My code for replacing '$' with '':**

```
if ('$' in str(df_column[column]) == True):
  new_val = [x.strip('$') for x in df_column[column].astype('str')]
  df_column.replace(column.values,values = new_val, inplace = True)
```

I am trying to do for a single column as of now, ideally would want to deal with all columns containing '$'. So df_column is thedataframe and and column is a list containing the column names grp_m1---grp_m4.

**Result:**

There is no error thrown but there are no changes in the column values.

**Expected Output:**

```
grp_m1      grp_m2      grp_m3      grp_m4
50-75     50-75     50-75     50-75
50-75     50-75     50-75     50-75
150-175   150-175   150-175   150-175
100-125   100-125   100-125   100-125
150-175   125-150   125-150   125-150
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I had used the solution provided :

```
if ('$' in str(df_column[column]) == True):
   df_column.values.replace('\$', '',inplace = True, regex=True)
```

But there is no change in the values in the dataframe.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823695/2336654

Comment: try to use applymap and pass as a function something like that: `func = lambda x: re.sub('\$', '', x) if type(x)==str and '$' in x else x`